# convert UTF-8 string into ASCII to save in ascii character set database column in Java

Tags: java

I have non English text say "你好" which i had to store in ASCII character set DB column. So thought to encode to ascii character set and while displaying from DB thought to decode the ascii to utf-8.

I am not able to do this using URLEncoder/URLDecoder because of the *.java file 'cp1252' text encoding. When I change *.java file encoding to UTF-8 is working fine. Cannot we do this with out changeing *.java text file encoding?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you try to save the data as some other data types like byte array?

Comment: ideographic characters cannot be represented in ASCII, so your concept of converting this text to ASCII is an impossibility. If you want your Java source code to contain non-ASCII Strings and not care about the source files' encoding, you can use Java's unicode escape notation. For instance, your two characters could be represented in a Java source code as `"\u 4f60\u 597d"` (without the spaces)

Comment: @kumesana - Not an impossibility.  It depends on *how* he converts to ASCII. Fpr example, he could use base64 encoding of the UTF-8 representation.  But that is not recommended.  It would be better to change the column type, etc to something that directly supports UTF-8 encoded text.

Comment: @StephenC it is commonly enough implicit, that when you intend to do a conversion from one character encoding to another character encoding, by any other mean than just changing which character encoding you use, you will describe so. Everybody knows about escapes, so when not mentioned, the intent is clearly to not involve them.

Comment: @kumesana - I don't enirely understand what you are saying.  However, note that the OP mentions using URLEncode / URLDecode ... which is NOT a charset translation.  Since he has already included this in the conversation ... something like base64 is in scope too.

Comment: @StephenC I stand corrected. Thank you for this.

Comment: Another thing that you should consider and will result a mess: in UTF-8 many characters like that exotic one you showed us are represented in two bytes. The problem is when you define your columns, you give them length. From now you may be able to store only texts with half of the defined length (and try to validate your text by length)! Maybe that's why in Oracle you can specify the length of a varchar column in number of bytes or number of chars...

Comment: Exactly this was one of the main reason btw why we are using UTF-8 charset everywhere, from database level to java default encoding, jsp page encoding, xml encoding, etc.

Comment: Why would you not want to change all your source files to UTF-8? Other encodings have clearly let you down. Java source code is comprised of Unicode characters. UTF-8 is a very common character encoding for the Unicode character set.